# Does Reincarnation Exist in A Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I watch the *Game of Thrones* TV series and I play the strategy game *Game of Thrones: Ascent*, but I have not read any of the books other than the first chapter of the first book. In *Game of Thrones: Ascent*, there is a quest line to reincarnate, starting the game all over, allowing you to keep only certain things. Does this stem from a concept of reincarnation in the books or is it just a feature of the game?

Comment: Being reincarnated as an undead, yes. Being reincarnated as something else, not so much.

Comment: I don't know if this is an answer or just a comment.

Comment: Do you mean reincarnation or resurrection? I ask because I often confuse the two... I think there is a clear case for the latter, but only mild for the former (well, maybe if you count warging).

Comment: I know the difference and I mean reincarnation, not resurrection.

Comment: Getting converted into a ice-zombie is not reincarnation. That is just reanimation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the prologue to *A Game of Thrones*, we see [Ser Waymar Royce](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Waymar_Royce) become a [wight](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wight). Wights are mindless creatures, somewhat like zombies.

Spoiler ASOS:

> Later in the series, we see [the red priest](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_Priest) [Thoros of Myr](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Thoros) resurrect [Lord Beric Dondarrion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Beric_Dondarrion). Beric seems to retain his old personality, although his memory seems to deteriorate.

Spoiler ASOS:

> We also meet [Coldhands](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Coldhands), a wight in service of [the Three-Eyed Crow](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Three-eyed_crow), who seems to be different from other wights.
>
> We see the spirit of the skinchanger [Orell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Orell) live on inside the body of his eagle.

Spoiler ADWD:

> In the prologue to ADWD, we see the skinchanger [Varamyr Sixskins](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Varamyr) transfer his spirit into his wolf companion.

So, can you die and come back in ASOIAF? Yes, you can. Can you be reincarnated as someone or something else, like Beric being reborn as a butterfly? No. Can your spirit be transferred to other bodies? Yes.

Comment: @FuzzyMcNubNubs You're welcome.

Comment: I remember Arya asking someone can her father be reincarnated after seeing someone else be reincarnated, but maybe I am mistaken. The person said her father couldn't be.

Comment: Arya asked Thoros if he could resurrect someone without a head. Not many times, just the ones. He figured out she was talking about Ned, and said a lot of things, but in the end, the answer was no.

Comment: First spoiler: Is there evidence that this is REALLY a resurrection or maybe he was just unconcious and the rest has been PR for some god?

Comment: @Trollwut We saw him die in Arya's perspective. Then he came back.

Answer (score 5):

The red priests of R'hllor have the ability to

> bring people back from the dead, such as Beric Dondarrion and Catelyn Stark.

Whether or not that counts as re-incarnation is highly debatable.

Comment: And there's nothing saying that this is only something they can do. Many people seem to think it's nothing to do with the faith and just part of some magic that is learned.

Comment: @Rob, true, but so far we haven't see anyone else do that. What Mirri Maz Duur did is definitely not in the same category.

Answer (score 2):

**Re-incarnation? Not so much in the exact sense of the word; therefore it seems that that is a feature of the game only.** (Barring the ability for certain characters to be **re-animated** using magic by the [Red Priests](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_priest)).

However, consider that there seem to be many parallels between historical figures and current storylines of certain characters.

## The Prince That Was Promised

**[Azor Ahai](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Azor_Ahai)** seems to be the closest contender for this title; **Azor Ahai** was a hero who lived in the [Age of Heroes](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Age_of_Heroes) and was believed to have lived during the [Long Night](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_Long_Night) and was responsible for defeating the [Others](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Others).

[The Prince That Was Promised](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_prince_that_was_promised) (TPTWP) is said to be the return of this hero. **[Rhaegar Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaegar_Targaryen)** believed that this hero was to be born of his line (he believed it to be his son **[Aegon VI](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Rhaegar))**), whereas many believe this true return of this hero to be

> [**Jon Snow**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Snow); from a union between Rhaegar Targaryen and [**Lyanna Stark**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lyanna_Stark)<sub>[[1]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Snow#Parentage), [[2]](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/128631-rlj-v-141/)</sub>

TPTWP was mentioned in [The House of the Undying](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_of_the_Undying) during [**Daenerys**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daenerys_Targaryen)' visions<sub>[[3]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_of_the_Undying#Visions_in_the_House_of_the_Undying)</sub>, where she sees her deceased older brother Rhaegar conversing with a woman (believed to be his wife, **[Elia Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Elia_Martell)**), and speaking of their newborn son (believed to be Aegon VI) saying:

> He is the prince that was promised, and his is the song of ice and fire.
> <sup>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: Book Two - A Clash of Kings, Chapter 48 ([Daenerys IV](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Clash_of_Kings-Chapter_48)).*</sup>

## The Night's King

This one is a slightly less definitive one. No one knows the true purpose of the original **[Night's King](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Night%27s_King)**; but many are likening **[Stannis Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stannis_Baratheon)** to the original Night's King for his "unholy" union with [**The Red Woman**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Melisandre) (Melisandre).

It is unclear whether or not The Night's King was the same character as **[The Great Other](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Great_Other)** (TGO), but there definitely seems to be a growing climax towards a clash between TPTWP and TGO. Whether or not TGO will become manifest, and if so, whether or not it will be the same ageless character, or a re-incarnation is yet to be discovered.

---

**1.** http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Snow#Parentage
**2.** http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/128631-rlj-v-141/
**3.** http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_of_the_Undying#Visions_in_the_House_of_the_Undying

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its theme found its way onto the show in Season 5 Episode 7. Maester Aemon of the knights watch says in a different voice "Egg! I  dreamed that I was old" on his death bed. It is theorized that the masester had just opened his eyes as the newly reincarnated boy without fully dying yet. This answer is my favorite as it may not be cannon as it's drawn from the prospective of the TV show and without the books.

Comment: I haven't heard of this theory before, but it doesn't make sense. Also, there's 0 evidence for it and so it's just pure fan made speculation.